# In VueJs can i run a function after replacing the url?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In VueJs i have these functions:

```
domainLogin() {
  const self = this;
  const api = this.$store.state.api + "domainLogin";

  axios
    .post(api, {
      registry: self.registry,
      password: self.password
    })
    .then((response) => {
      this.redirect(response.data.tenant)

      self.$store.commit("auth", response.data.access_token)

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      self.$message("Erro", error.response, "error");
    });
},

redirect(domain){
  window.location.replace("https://"+ domain +".example.com.br")    
},
```

I need to store the access_token after the redirect because i need to save it in the new localStorage of the domain. I want this because i want the user to be redirected and already logged in the new domain.

The domain i'm redirecting is in the same application as the main domain, the only thing that changes is the domain.

Is this the way to do it? If so how? Or should i try another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it this way, once the `redirect` function executes, it will continue executing the other code in the scope.

One solution, you can send the `access token` as a query parameter to the new domain, and use it there.

For example.

```
domainLogin() {
  const self = this;
  const api = this.$store.state.api + "domainLogin";

  axios
    .post(api, {
      registry: self.registry,
      password: self.password
    })
    .then((response) => {
      this.redirect(response.data.tenant, response.data.access_token)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      self.$message("Erro", error.response, "error");
    });
},

redirect(domain, token){
  window.location.replace("https://"+ domain +".example.com.br"+"?access_token=" 
 + token)    
},
```